# wxWidgets - Event table vs Connect()?

Tags: c++, event-handling, wxwidgets

I have just started learning wxWidgets, version 3.0, with C++. I have noted, that event handling in wxWidgets is done by Event tables. But one tutorial also mentioned Connect() - actually it just said : " this tutorial will be using event tables, not Connect() " .

I would like to know, what is the philosophy behind Event tables and behind Connect() ? What is the difference, when is one more suitable than the other... Thank you.

Comment: One google query later: http://wxwidgets.blogspot.com/2007/01/in-praise-of-connect.html ;-)

Comment: Actually, you should use neither. Use Bind / Unbind instead, those are safer than Connect / Disconnect because they do more compile time checks.

Comment: @KristianDuske - do you know any examples / tutorial that show how to use Bind() ? I am pretty sure that as a novice I won't be able to figure it out on my own. Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, don't use `Connect()` which was superseded by [Bind()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a0f30c8fa5583b4a5f661897d63de3b62) which is better in every way.

Second, both static (using event tables) and dynamic (using `Bind()`) methods of handling events work and you can use whichever you prefer. Personally, I recommend using `Bind()` because

1. It is much more flexible: can be used to connect the event on one object to any other object or even a free function or, in C++11, [a lambda](http://wxwidgets.blogspot.com/2013/08/wxwidgets-and-c-11.html).
2. It is safer and catches most common errors such as using wrong event handler signature at compile time.
3. It is "dynamic", i.e. you can connect and disconnect the handler at any time.

The main advantages of the event tables are that

1. They are slightly shorter, especially in pre 3.0 versions.
2. They are much more common in documentation, examples, tutorials, ... just because they had a 15 year head start on `Bind()`.

However they are clumsier to use because they require subclassing (deriving a new class from) an object in order to handle non-command events in it and they don't detect all errors at compile-time allowing you to write code that compiles fine but crashes at run-time.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can you point to some good examples / tutorials that show how to use Bind() ? I noticed, as you have said, that Event tables are everywhere. But as a novice I doubt I can learn to use Bind() without any example.

Comment: `samples/event` contains a simple example of using `Bind()` (in addition to all the other event handling methods). The [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html) also contains some simple examples.